# Vue.js 2 Cannot change value of data property inside method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to update `taxParentId` with the new id that i retrieve with my API call inside the `getTaxParentId` function, but I cannot get it to change. I can console.log the value fine inside the method, but it won't update it. It seems to be an issue of scope, but i have set `$this = this` to take care of this, however, it is not working.

the `getPostType` method works fine and properly updates the data value.

```
var newVue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return{
      posts: [],
      taxonomy: '',
      postType: '',
      taxParentSlug: '',
      taxParentId: 0
    }
  },
  created (){
    let $this = this;
    this.getPostType(location.href);
    this.getTaxParent(location.href)
    this.getTaxParentId();
    this.getPosts();

  },
  methods: {
    getPostType: function(currentURL){
        if (currentURL.includes('residential')) {
            this.postType = 'residential';
        }else if(currentURL.includes('commercial')){
            this.postType = 'commercial';
        }else if (currentURL.includes('auto')) {
            this.postType = 'auto';
        }
    },
    getTaxParent: function(currentURL){
        if (currentURL.includes('solar')) {
            this.taxParentSlug = 'solar';
        }else if(currentURL.includes('decorative')){
            this.taxParentSlug = 'decorative';
        }else if (currentURL.includes('safety-security')) {
            this.taxParentSlug = 'safety-security';
        }
    },
    getTaxParentId: function(){
        let $this = this;

        axios
          .get(apiRoot + $this.postType + '-categories')
          .then(function (response) {
            response.data.forEach(function(item){
                if (item.slug == $this.taxParentSlug) {
                    $this.taxParentId = item.id;
                }
            });
          }
        )
    },
    getPosts: function(){
        let $this = this;

        console.log(apiRoot + $this.postType + '-categories?parent=' + $this.taxParentId)
        axios

          .get(apiRoot + $this.postType + '-categories?parent=' + $this.taxParentId)
          .then(function (response) {
            $this.posts = response.data;
            console.log($this.posts)
          }
        )
    },
  },

});
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Have you shared it exactly as it is written in your application?

Comment: yep. Copied and pasted. That's why i am baffled

Comment: What is the value of currentURL when you console log it?

Comment: What makes you think it isn't changing? Where do you use it? Also where is the `getTaxParent` method?

Comment: i took it out since it wasn't really relevant, but i added it back in

Comment: ```currentURL``` is the current url and works fine. ```getPostType``` and ```getTaxParent``` work as expected and updated the data values properly. I use it in another function to make an API call called ```getPosts```

Comment: I would share your whole component code, as the issue is almost certainly something that you don't think is relevant.

Comment: i updated it with everything. When I call ```getPosts()``` the ```taxParentId``` is still the default value i gave it of ```0```

Comment: `getPosts` send the http request to backend with `this.parentid=0` because `getTaxParentId` is async

Comment: Ok, so your `getTaxParentId` makes an async call, so the `then` callback won't have executed when the `getPosts` gets called. You should return the `axios` call in your `getTaxParentId` function: `return axios.get(...)`. This will return the `Promise` and so then you can add a `then` handler for the `getTaxParentId` itself and then put the `getPosts` call within the callback: `this.getTaxParentId().then(() => this.getPosts())`

Comment: Just figured that out. Needed to wait for the call to return data. Thank you for the help. Silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the async, add watchers to your data, and log there.

```
watch:{
    posts(value){console.log(value))},
    taxParentId(value){console.log(value))}
}
```

Ideally you would get a promise from each call, and then wait for them all.  If one call is dependent on another, you need to put the second call in a then() block, or even better, await it (async/await)

Using this, all you need to do is return the promise, and it will be synchronized.

```
  async created (){
    let $this = this;
    await this.getPostType(location.href);
    await this.getTaxParent(location.href)
    await this.getTaxParentId();
    await this.getPosts();
  },
```

So much cleaner then chaining `then` blocks.  You can wrap the entire block in a SINGLE catch, and trap all exceptions AND all rejections.  Of course, if the calls are not dependent, you may want to call them in parallel and not await.

Comment: When I do that, I get the proper value for ```taxParentId``` that I am setting in the function, but when i make the API call in ```getPosts``` the value is still the default value

Comment: Call getPosts() in the return of getTaxParentId().  You are calling it before the other function returns.

Comment: i just changed it to that and it worked. No clue why i didnt do that the first time

Comment: I will add another suggestion to solution too...  I'm a big fan of async/await.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using promises, you should be able to build a promise chain to solve your async issue.

Take your current function:
```javascript
    getTaxParentId: function(){
        let $this = this;

```
    axios
      .get(apiRoot + $this.postType + '-categories')
      .then(function (response) {
        response.data.forEach(function(item){
            if (item.slug == $this.taxParentSlug) {
                $this.taxParentId = item.id;
            }
        });
      }
    )
},
```

and make it return a value, even if it is just the response
```javascript
    getTaxParentId: function(){
        let $this = this;

```
    axios
      .get(apiRoot + $this.postType + '-categories')
      .then(function (response) {
        response.data.forEach(function(item){
            if (item.slug == $this.taxParentSlug) {
                $this.taxParentId = item.id;
            }
        });
        return response
      }
    )
},
```

Then in your `created()` function, you can chain the call..

```
created (){
    let $this = this;
    this.getPostType(location.href);
    this.getTaxParent(location.href)
    this.getTaxParentId()
     .then(function (response) {
        this.getPosts();
    })
  },
```

This should force `this.getPosts()` to wait for `getTaxParentId` to be complete.